# From where does the Common Mode 1.2V of LVDS comes from?

Tags: lvds

I am trying to understand the LVDS signalling.

But from where do we get the 1.2V common mode voltage?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> But from where do we get the 1.2V common mode voltage?

That depends, there are several ways to generate an LVDS signal with a common mode voltage of 1.2 V.

Generally an LVDS signal can be generated like this:

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3662).

However, here the common mode voltage is actually **undefined**!

If the top current source is actually not 3.5 mA but 3.499 mA and the bottom current source is 3.500 mA then the bottom current source "pulls harder" and that will pull down the common mode level of the LVDS signal. In the real world current sources never have exactly identical values so with this circuit we cannot set the commonmode level easily. (There is a solution though, a *common mode feedback loop* which would adjust the value of one of the 3.5 mA current sources such that the common mode level becomes 1.2 V. For an LVDS circuit, that's a bit overkill and too complicated, there are simpler solutions).

A simple way to set the common mode voltage is by using some resistors. Here's an example:

[image]

Image from [here](http://bmc.bu.edu/bmc/asd/lvds/theory.html).

The two 250 ohm resistors to a 1.2 V reference voltage set the common mode voltage.

As these resistors are for "DC only" they need to have such a value that they do not influence the impedance of the LVDS lines too much. This means the resistors need to have a value that is significantly larger than 100 ohm which is the value of the termination resistor. For the LVDS signal those two 250 ohm resistors behave like they are in series so that makes then 500 ohms, which is significantly higher than 100 ohms.

The circuit to set the common mode voltage can be at the receiver side or the transmitter side. Since it is DC, the location does not matter much.

Comment: I am not understanding. I think I am missing the basics somewhere along my question. My query is, in the LVDS signal communication, we only have a current source of 3.5mA and a termination resistor of 100Ohm. So, Ideally, when we measure the voltage across the Resistor, we must get only 350mV,right? But we get a common mode voltage of 1.2V at the center and from there, we get the +/-350mV. My query is, from where is the 1.2V coming? From which source? From the Transmitter side or Receiver side are we getting this 1.2V? Please clarify

Comment: That is exactly what my answer is explaining. The 2nd picture shows VRef = 1.2 V and that resistors are used to connect that 1.2 V to the LVDS lines. I am unsure how I can explain this more than I already did. *But we get a common mode voltage of 1.2V at the center and from there, we get the +/-350mV* Note that the 1.2 V is the **average** voltage of the LVDS lines **referenced to ground** and that the +/-350 mV is the **differential voltage between the LVDS lines**. Those are **VERY different** voltages. Please study differential signals! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling

Comment: can you please tell me what would be the voltage on the pin Y & YN?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4vf5X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the first schematic of Bimpelrekkie:
he correctly states that common mode voltage is undefined there.

But think about a known voltage reference U of 2.5V at the high-side current source.

Common mode voltage will be U/2 = 1.25V (assuming well balanced current sources).